# Im trying to prove that a star can be described by a polytrope by deriving the polytropic relation of $P\sim p^n$ from the stellar structure equations

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, density, stellar-physics

Suppose that in a star, the only source of energy generation is radioactive decay, so the energy production per unit mass is constant and independent of density and temperature. Further suppose that the opacity is given by Kramer’s' law. How can I prove that  the structure of the star is described by the polytrope of form  $P\sim p^n$?

Comment: Not following. The energy transport is either radiative or convective. In both these cases the star can be represented by a polytrope.

Comment: It would be actually the radiative zero idealized star with a polytropic index of 3.5.